# style input to hug content size in html+css (no js)

Tags: html, css, input

I'm coding in blazor, so I'd favor solutions based on html-css and not js. I want my input field to hug its content. not have a fixed width in pixels.
This is how it looks like, notice the amount of empty space at the right of "Odri"

[image]

This is how I want it to look like:
[image]

Notice how the edit box wraps around the content and the width space is used by the last item (via flex-grow :1)

I achieved this behavior using "cotenteditable" on a div or a span, but this is undesirable because div or spans do not have attached methods like @onedit, @onfocusout and other useful stuff that blazor has for inputs or textarea

Note: I will need similar tools for text area in the near future, so... extra points for solutions that work also for textarea

This is my code so far:

```
<div class="d-flex">
 <input @bind=Player.Name @onfocusout=StoreChangesToDB>   <!--This is input that needs to shrink-->
 <div> - @Player.Profession |</div>
 <div class="littleText flex-grow-1">@Player.Motivation</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no experience with blazor, but this is not possible only with HTML and CSS.

Comment: [These](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/) are the possible solutions

Comment: yup,,, Im accepting will end up using js :(